# How to decode the pixels in a JPG in App Engine (using pure python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jpeg

Using python App Engine I need to convert a JPG image that is one 9 MB file (of Pakistan's floods) into many PNG tiles.

For the PNG part, I already know how to use PyPNG, which is great. Note: PIL cant be used with App Engine.

So how do I decode the JPG into pixel data?

Comment: Does this need to happen online? One way to think about this is to generate the tiles on your computer using PIL and then upload the tiles to GAE. But I'm sure you've thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Image](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass.html) class and `crop` and `execute_transforms` to encode as png?

Note: You should provide relevant part of your code

Comment: i think the image api service has a 1MB size limit. My file is 9MB.

Comment: @indiehacker: From the docs: "maximum data size of image sent to service: 32 megabytes" (http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/appengine/docs/python/images/overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the efforts [here](http://davidf.sjsoft.com/files/pyjpeg/) to get a pure python JPEG Parser. Why the absolute need to use App Engine ? If you want more flexible library usage try EC2.